# Android - I need a "editor view" with the ability to add raw text and multi media

Tags: android, html

my plan is to programm an editor with the ability to add text and multi media (pictures, videos and audio). Since I'm a programming newbie, I turn to you and I hope you can answer me the following questions:

1. First of all how to realize a raw text editor?
   My idea is to use an EditText that takes the whole layout of the activity. Is it okay? Should I pay attention to anything in this approach?
2. How to add multi media to the editor?
   My idea was to represent the EditText content (text and multi media) as a html document, and make the EditText-View work like a webbrowser that understand html. But if an user tries to add some content (picture, audio etc.) the html document (content of my EditText) will change dynamically. I read that java script allows me to add dynamically html. So my question: its possible to work with java script inside my android java code?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all how to realize a raw text editor? My idea is to use an EditText that takes the whole layout of the activity. Is it okay? Should I pay attention to anything in this approach?

Yes you can play with `EditText` attributes like change background color and things like that, just try the `EditText` suggestion list

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: Thanks! thats what I needed.